# $\int_{[1,- i]} \frac{1}{z}$ where $[1,- i]$ is the straight line joining the first point to the second point

Tags: complex-analysis

> $\int_{[1, -i]} \frac{1}{z}$ where $[1, -i]$ is the straight line
> joining the first point to the second point

I am trying to evaluate this using the fundamental theorem of calculus for path integrals

If I use the branch of log $(-\pi, \pi)$ I get the answer as $(\frac{-\pi}2)i$

If I use the branch of log $(\frac{\pi}2, \frac{5\pi}{2})$, I get the answer as $\frac{3\pi}2$

For the first case, I have $\log(z) = \ln|z| + i\theta$ where $\theta = \text{arg} z \in (-\pi, \pi)$

$$\int_{[1,-i]} \frac{dz}{z} = \log(-i) - \log (1) \\= \ln|-i| + i\theta_{-i} - \ln|1| - i\theta_1 = 0 + (\frac{-\pi}2)i - 0 - 0i \\= (\frac{-\pi}2)i$$

For the second case, I have $\log(z) = \ln|z| + i\theta$ where $\theta = \text{arg} z \in (\pi/2, 5\pi/2)$

$$\int_{[1,-i]} \frac{dz}{z} = \log(-i) - \log (1) \\= \ln|-i| + i\theta_{-i} - \ln|1| - i\theta_1 \\= 0 + \frac{3\pi}2i - 0 - 0i = \frac{3\pi}2i$$
Are both these answers correct?

Comment: These should both be the same answer regardless of what branch we choose. Can you show your work? If we see your computations, we can tell you where the mistake was.

Comment: @RiversMcForge can you please check my calculations.

Comment: The mistake is in the second one. If you use the $( \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{5 \pi}{2})$ branch of complex log, then $\log(1) = 2 \pi i$, not $0$.

Comment: @RiversMcForge thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point $i = \exp(\frac{\pi}{2} i) = \cos(\pi/2) + i \sin(\pi/2)$ is on the branch cut for your second computation, so that computation is not legal.

Comment: I am really sorry, there was a typo.. it was $[1,-i]$ not $[1, i]$. Can you please tell me now if both answers are correct